# WordPress admin: show draft pages in page attributes parent page dropdown

Tags: wordpress

For clarity - here is a picture of the box I am talking about in this question:
[image: Screenshot of post parent dropdown list]

**Background:** I have built a relatively complex WP site for a client which is more of a CMS than a blog and relies on a hierarchy of pages being built. (Well, they're actually custom post types with `'hierarchical' => true` set)

**My question:** is it possible to show draft (or pending review) pages in the page attributes 'Parent page' dropdown list? Without this, it means making each page live before the whole section is ready - and that's not a suitable solution.

**What I've tried:**

- Looking for an action which gets called to build the list (can't find one)
- Looking in the source code for where the list is created (it's built with [wp_dropdown_pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_pages) which doesn't appear to let you choose the post status)
- Looking for plugins which provide this functionality

Comment: Might try asking this on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I was unaware of that site - will give it a try! Thanks, ars :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very nice question!

The following does it. One filter is for the edit page screen and the other for the Quick Edit menu.
Tested with a hierarchical custom post type.

```
add_filter( 'page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args', 'so_3538267_enable_drafts_parents' );
add_filter( 'quick_edit_dropdown_pages_args', 'so_3538267_enable_drafts_parents' );

function so_3538267_enable_drafts_parents( $args )
{
    $args['post_status'] = 'draft,publish,pending';
    return $args;
}
```

[image: drafts enabled as parents]

Comment: I gave up on solving this problem - I just tried this solution and it works perfectly, I'm pleased to see that there are filters for these now :)

Comment: Where do you add this code? UPDATE: Nevermind, in functions.php. :)